# new (Json)Response shows blank page (Symfony HttpFoundation)

Tags: php, symfony, response, psr-7, symfony-http-foundation

I am using the HttpFoundation in my small project: `use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse as JsonResponse;`

Unfortunately all my responses (tried `JsonResponse`, `Response` and `BinaryFileResponse`) only return a blank page, no errors and the code gets executed normally, e.g.

```
/* Get Inputs */
if (!$data = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'url', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'result' => 'error',
        'message' => 'URL is invalid or missing'
    ));
}else{
     return new JsonResponse(array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'message' => 'FINE'
    ));
```

There are no errors in the logs either.

Any ideas how to approach the issue?

//UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION

```
$json = new JsonResponse(array(
    'result' => 'error',
    'message' => 'Encrypt is invalid or missing'
));

echo $json;
```

returns `HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json {"result":"error","message":"Encrypt is invalid or missing"}`

but why does the `return` not work?

Comment: what if you echo the response? Are you invoking the service via Ajax?

Comment: No, it's a direct call and "echo" gets displayed fine

Comment: Even if you put the `JsonResponse` in a variable?

Comment: is display_errors set to on?

Comment: display_errros is on. `$json = new Json Response...` and then `echo $json` returns `HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json {"result":"error","message":"Encrypt is invalid or missing"}` so there is seomthing wrong with the `return` statement?

Comment: Which framework? Apparently your application does not handle `Response` objects returned from the controller.

Comment: Well, not using a full stack framework, but the Response I get with this: `use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse as JsonResponse;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the full stack framework, so you need to be sure that your front controller or equivalent calls `$response->send();` to [deliver the response](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#sending-the-response) to the client.

Comment: 'You may award in 23 hours' - Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It's addition to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34392678/3612353):

```
$response = new JsonResponse(array(
    'result' => 'error',
    'message' => 'Encrypt is invalid or missing'
));
$response->send();
```